# Inserting character vector elements in a single character value

Tags: r, rmysql

I have a column of names in my dataframe in R and I am trying to create a text variable of an SQL query out of the names as follows...

```
select * from *table* where *name* in (*data$name[1,]*, *data$name[2,]*...)
```

While this can be done this using a for loop and `paste` function, but I am hoping to find an alternative to using a loop. Any idea on how to go about this ?

Comment: Are you using `sqldf` package?

Comment: Using RMySQL package

Comment: Please show some reproducible example

Comment: Say I have a the following vector of names with following elements...
" aa1",
"aa2"
"ab3"
"aa5"
"bb7"

I need to create a character variable x with the value as...
 "select * from table where name in (aa1, aa2, ab3, aa5,bb7)"

Comment: Please check this this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for making reproducible example

Comment: Ok...

If we use the following code to generate a character vector using the built in 'mtcars' dataframe in r...      

`> x <- row.names(mtcars)`...  We will get the following vector...  
`"Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4" "Datsun 710" ... `

    Now I need to create a vector y as follows...    

`"select * from table where name in ('Mazda RX4','Mazda RX4','Datsun 710',...  )"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
x <- paste0("select * from table where name in (", paste(names(data), collapse=", "), ")")
```